# Are Hom, Ext, Tor and the tensor product isomorphic on objects when restricted to finite abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A,B$ be finite abelian groups. Is it true that
$$Hom(A,B)\cong Ext^1(A,B) \cong A \otimes B \cong Tor^1(A,B)=0?$$
I seem to recall something along these lines, but just wanted to make sure (or get a counterexample!) This is true for cyclic groups, and so it should follow for general finite abelian groups just by the fact that the functors commute with direct sums, right?

Comment: If $A=B\neq 0$ then ${\rm Hom}(A,B)\neq 0$.  Have you tried to compute some examples?

Comment: For cyclic groups these isomorphisms do indeed hold, but they are not zero. If $A = \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and $B = \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$, then they are all isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/(m,n)\mathbb Z$, which is zero if and only if $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Your last question is true. These functors commute with direct sums and hence you can conclude for all finite abelian groups.